# Earth engine Configuración de credenciales de autenticación PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied windows

Tags: cmd, windows10

Estoy instalando el API de Earth Engine Python, al momento de configurar las  credenciales de autenticación con el comando:

```
python -c "import ee; ee.Initialize ()"
```

me sale el error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\arles/.config/earthengine/credentials'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Ademas de eso solo queda decir que estoy trabajando con win 10 y que si el 
  cmd tiene permisos de administrador.Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí les dejo un vídeo donde se configura correctamente el paquete de earth engine y no tengan este problema: https://youtu.be/Zr_cItq9wJU

El error surgió principalmente por la generación de credenciales y esto paso a raíz que previamente debí haber ejecutado el comando:

```
pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client
```

El cual es necesario para la autenticación, después de eso asegurarse que en la ruta:

```
C:\\users\\{nombre de usuario}\\.config\\
```

En dicha ruta no exista la carpeta creada earthengine de ahi el error PermissionError: [Errno 13],luego de eso ejecutar el comando:

```
earthengine authenticate
```

Este comando permitirá obtener un código de autenticación que se deberá pegar en el terminal.

Finalmente ejecutar el comando que me generaba el error y todo ira con éxito:

```
python -c "import ee; ee.Initialize()"
```